# How do I recover a hard drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I recently lost a hard drive. The computer is old (I built it 7+ years) but has been reliable until this event. No warnings of any kind (Windows, SMART, etc.) and one day the drive just disappeared from My Computer / Windows Explorer.

The disk appears in Disk Management but my only option is to initialize it. DM shows a 2TB block of unallocated space.

Is there anything I can do to breathe life into this drive to create one last back?

Comment: Send it to a recovery specialist>>>https://www.lowcostrecovery.com/

Comment: Ca n you use ddrescue or similar to clone the contents of the drive?  After doing that, maybe try photorec to recover partitioning?

Comment: Davidgo, photorec is a file carver and not a partition repair tool.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will never be able to repair the existing partition(s).

I am sorry to report SMART support was bad 7 years ago.  If your BIOS doesn't support SMART then you won't get any warnings.  Even beyond that SMART usually had to be enabled in the BIOS.

However, 7 years ago the vast majority of BIOS didn't have smart support, and even then it might not have worked.

I have never seen windows ever display a SMART error for the user directly.  Maybe in the event viewer, but almost no one looks at the event viewer.

It is still mainly up to the user to manually check the SMART values.

If the motor died replacing it is going to be tricky.  You would have to basically replace it with the same 7 year old motor.  The only way to come close is to a buy another drive exactly the same as you have and swap it out.

You can use ddrescue and/or photorec to recover the data, and place it on a new drive, if the drive is accessible.

Basically your going to have to send the drive in for professional recovery and if you have to ask how much it costs you probably can't afford it.